# Linq to SQL SP is returning multiple recordsets when I only want one!

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Hi I have the following SP, however when I use LINQ to SQL it generates 2 multiple recordsets. For my sanity I am trying to fathom out what it is in the stored procedure that is doing this and would like to only return a single recordset... Can any help?

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckToken] 
        @LoginId int
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @failures INT

        SET @failures = (SELECT COUNT(loginid) FROM auditerrorcode WHERE 
                    errorid = 1012 AND loginid = @loginid
                    AND datecreated >  DATEADD(hh, -1, getdate())
                )


        IF @failures > 10 UPDATE [login] SET [IsDisabled]=1 WHERE loginid = @loginid

        SELECT * FROM [Login] WHERE LoginId = @LoginId

END
```

Comment: Are the two results identical?  Do they have the same LoginId?

Comment: No, the first recordset contains all the fields for login and the second contains a single field for IsDisabled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Guys....

I looked again in the DBML file generated and deleted the CheckToken method which had multiple result sets defined. I then regenerated and now I get what I expected, one recordset

Looks like the mods I made to the SP has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your procedure stand alone and rule out your not getting two rows because there are two rows being returned for the ID you are passing in. Do this in SQL Managment Studio with a

EXEC dbo.CheckToken 999

Make sure to use the same @LoginID that you are calling from your .NET code.